# Dynamically creating string for shell_exec doesn't work

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I dynamically create a string and pass it to shell_exec, this doesn't work.

```
$b = 'args1';
shell_exec('java -jar jar1.jar '.$b.' args2');
```

But when I use a fixed string it works fine:

```
shell_exec('java -jar jar1.jar args1 args2');
```

I am thinking that somewhere there is a problem with the string created. I am not sure how to resolve this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's impossible. Show the real code, there's probably something wrong with how you're setting `$b`.

Comment: Maybe you need to quote the argument, or you left out a space around it. You should use `escapeshellarg()` when inserting dynamic arguments into a shell command.

Comment: @Barmar using escapeshellarg() on each variable will solve this problem.